# Reputation points sunk by a third (20 points)... overnight?

Tags: discussion, questions

I woke up this morning to see that, after a decent rise over time, my reputation points suddenly sank by a third overnight.  Unless I'm misreading it, the note regarding this sudden change seemed to indicate that the cause for this was that one of my (approximately ten) posted questions had been removed; thus I lost a third of my reputation points in one fell swoop.

For what it's worth, the removed question has been up for weeks, with a number of views and, over time, mixed up and downvotes.  I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I tried to search Stack Overflow help on this subject and came upon some text that indicated that if there are upvotes or downvotes on a question from the same SO participant, that this can alter the reputation points of the person who posted the question. I don't think this is even possible, but (since it's *my* reputation points that have dropped) it may be worth mentioning here that I've never cast votes on my own questions.

It may also be worth mentioning that there's nothing I have done on SO for weeks; other than visiting the site to view other people's answers to a variety of questions.  So there's no recent activity on my part that explains the reputation points drop.

Can anyone offer some feedback?

Comment: I can see a deleted question if I have a link to it, but not otherwise.

Comment: If it actually had "mixed up and down votes" while accounting for "a third" of your reputation (so, what, 20 points pre-drop?), then it would have been strongly negative in score, since upvotes grant you 10 reputation each but downvotes take away only 2.

Comment: If your Qt (Question) had 3xUV's (+30Pts) and 5xDV's (-10Pts), => Score = -2, and no Answer(s), then it will get automatically roomba'd (=deleted) after 30 days, which could explain the loss of 30-10=20Pts.

Comment: It was deleted automatically with score +3/-5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78057896/when-string-contents-need-to-be-monitored-during-a-loop-what-is-best-alternativ

Comment: It's not clear what feedback you are looking for. The question got deleted so the reputation gained is now lost. If you can explain what else you are looking for, we can explain.

Comment: Perhaps the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) rules are also relevant here.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk A lot of helpful answers here, but to address yours specifically; the link to my removed question is 

[basic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78057896/when-string-contents-need-to-be-monitored-during-a-loop-what-is-best-alternativ?noredirect=1#comment137767459_78057896)

By the way, one of the later comments on that question was somebody saying the question seemed legitimate and should be taken out of its 'removed' status and reopened.  A bit sorry that didn't happen.  Maybe question would have gotten another Up vote or two.  Guess we'll never know.